# sudo access to view/edit a crontab

Tags: unix, centos, sudo, crontab, sudoers

I wish to be able to edit, or at least view, a crontab that is on a server.

Should I not be able to run this to do so:

```
sudo crontab -u root
```

When I do, I get this error:

> Sorry, user crmpicco is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/crontab -u
>   root' as root on crmpiccoStaging.

I am running CentOS 5.6 (Final).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using sudo, the user that executes crontab is automatically root, so in theory, adding "root" for crontab is not neccessary. Try either "`sudo crontab -e`" for editing or "`sudo su`", followed by "`crontab -e`" and see if it helps.

**Edit**: It's possible that you lack the rights to sudo on your server, are you sure it's set up correctly? (your user being in the sudoers file)

Comment: I can't actually _view_ the sudoers file `[crmpicco@crmpiccoStaging watp]$ cat /etc/sudoers` that gives me `cat: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied`

Comment: Sudoers can only be viewed by Superusers. That means you have to log in as root and configure it, if that did not happen yet. So if `sudo visudo` tells you you don't have the permissions, you are not in the sudoers file yet. If it works, and you can theoretically edit the file you should have sufficient permissions.

Comment: OK, so I need "root" to add me to the list of sudoers before I can re-try this?

Comment: Yep. That's exactly what you need to do.